# B2C Custom Policy: Is there any way to remove an entry from a StringCollection claim?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Considering the transformations availabe for StringCollection claims listed below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations

Is there any way to remove an entry from a StringCollection claim?

Comment: In nutshell, no. But what is your scenario?

Comment: Implementing a Consent solution using a Using a REST service and content UI with JavaScript. The journey stores of <AppId><Consented Scopes> in a StringCollection claim. When user deselects a consent, I need to update or delete the relevant string collection item.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal, can I repopulate a StringCollection? if that possible, it covers the delete requirment when a new collection comes from REST call.

Comment: you can use stringJoin and stringSplit transformations to achive this. The only problem is stringReplace does not take dynamic values and not static valies

Comment: Is this using the dynamic email sample (to draw dynamic controls to the user based on data from a REST API)?

Comment: @JasSuri, it is related to that one. The idea is to have a proper data structure to have the capacity to store the partial consent for more than 100 apps per user with each app can have 10-20 scopes. With AAD, users must give consent to all or none of the scopes. The solution I am building the user gets a checkbox per scope. I call it partial consent.

Comment: What you should do is, have one textbox for presenting the consent strings, and one textbox that collects the selected checkboxes. This way, you dont need to modify the stringCollection, as youll have one that is dedicated to presenting the consent texts, and that just has the collected values. Basically the JS that draws the checkboxes should write the selection as a string into a seperate textbox. And then you check each item in the new textbox is found within the original stringCollection (to prevent the user manipulating it)